# using get_time to parse string, part of the format doesn't seem to register

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to parse a string of date with the format

`seconds:minutes:hour:dayInMonth:month:year`

For example: `58:48:20:12:8:1905`

In this code:

```cpp
struct std::tm time{};
std::istringstream stream(timeString);
stream >> std::get_time(&time, "%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y");
```

`timeString` value is the time values and I've checked that it is as I expect.

`get_time()` puts the values of `seconds:minutes:hour:dayInMonth` correctly inside the `time` variable, but the `month:year` values are not parsed and remain 0 in the variable.

I've tried other formats, such as `%mm:%YYYY`, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: When trying myself I succeeded with `"08"` for the month (and *exactly* for digits for the year). As far as I interpret the standard ([*'leading zeroes permitted but not required '*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) – and [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html)) this is *not* correct behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with GCC and Clang. It works on MSVC. Please have a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/TjGq9Yo96) example.

By 0-padding your month (i.e. `58:48:20:12:08:1905`), all implementations will correctly parse your time string.

Comment: Will apparently be fixed with next version: https://godbolt.org/z/8YTjW1r91